# Overcome query jam in dashboard.

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, lazy-loading

I have a laravel app and there is a dashboard where I'm showing around 30 blocks. Blocks data is coming from identical queries. As a result when I hit on dashboard page system execute 40+ queries.

I want to show block one by one as well as execute query. Seeking idea to reduce query jam and execute it one bye one.

Comment: what is it querying?  a mysql db?

Comment: yes i am using mysql

Comment: if the database is large, make sure it's optimized and properly indexed for performance. also check to see if mysql performance can be improved by using a tool such as mysqltuner. consider caching queries, or even caching the content of blocks - hope this helps :)

Comment: I used AJAX to let blocks of data load one by one. If one block was loaded, I loaded the next one. Not really the idea which is behind AJAX request, but queries are executed one after another this way.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag i am planning like you. Did you use jquery-lazy or others plugins?

Comment: No, just jQuery to make the requests easier to handle.